# Statistical test to check if data come from two different lines or just one

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, linear

I have a very basic problem, can you give me some insights on how to solve it, or just some keywords to search online?

I have two sets of points in $\mathbb{R}^2$, let say $S_1 = \{(x_i, y_i)\}_{i=1}^{N}$ and $S_2 = \{(x_i, y_i)\}_{i=1}^{M}$, the points of both sets seem to have a linear relation:

$$
y_i = mx_i + q
$$

But my hypotesis is that they "come" from two different lines, so for example the line with parameters $(m_1, q_1)$ for $S_1$ and parameters $(m_2, q_2)$ for $S_2$.

How can I test if they actually come from two different lines (and there is statistical significance) or from the same one?

Comment: Do you know which point $(x_i,y_i)$ belongs to which set? Moreover, are the slopes of the lines arbitrary and can be, e.g., vertical?

Comment: Yes I know to which set they belong. The slopes are not vertical. I have real data points, and visually on the scatter plot it seems the come from two slightly different lines. I would like to know if I can use a statistical tool to check if there is statistical significance in this observation

Comment: In this case the answer by @EdM solves this problem: if you use "treatment coding" (default in R) for the group label, then you can check whether the coefficients related to the group difference are different from zero; these are reported in the R `summary` of your model as `SS2` for the intercept and `x:S2` for the slope (look for stars at the end).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a standard application of an interaction term in a model.

With x as continuous-valued predictors and y as your outcomes, let S represent which `set` a data point belongs to, with `S1` specified as the reference value. In a standard symbolic representation of a linear model, you would write:

```
y ~ x + S + x:S
```

That model returns 4 coefficients:* an Intercept (your `q` for `S1`), a coefficient for `x` that represents the change in `y` per unit change in `x` for `S1`, a coefficient for `S` that represents the difference for set `S2` from the Intercept when `x = 0`, and an interaction coefficient that is the *extra difference* for `S2` (again, beyond what you predict for `S1`) for non-zero values of `x`.

Standard tests then indicate whether there is evidence that distinguishing `S1` from `S2` matters. This might be done by also fitting the simple model without considering `set`:

```
y ~ x
```

and comparing the two models with analysis of variance.

---

*This assumes that `S1` is represented numerically as 0 in your model and `S2` as 1. That's a typical coding of `set`, often done silently for you by statistical software.